# How to determine the size of a MySQL database, until a point in time?

Tags: mysql, database, rdbms

How can I determine the size of my MySQL database until a specific point in time? For example this query gives me the size of my database in GB, now:

```
SELECT  sum(round(((data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024 / 1024), 2))  as "Size in GB"
FROM information_schema.TABLES;
```

But how can I get what was the size of my database yesterday?

Comment: Run the query yesterday

Comment: @Strawberry How can I do this?

Comment: Unless you made a backup, you can't.

Comment: You could guestimate it - if you knew how many rows had been added since that point in time.  This isn't accurate at all as things like page size and index size aren't simply made to fit your rows.